# improve the animationon navigation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have an navigation on which there's a small image that move to the list item,based on the position of the cursor over the list. But for some reason there is some sort of lag, when i "mouseover" the other element

```
//MOVE MOUSE ICON -- Mouse over
$('#lava_menu li').mouseover(function(){
var pos = $(this).position();
$("#google").animate({
    left: pos.left,
    right: pos.right,
    top: pos.top,
    bottom: pos.bottom
    },"slow");   
    break;  
});


//MOVE MOUSE ICON --Mouse out
$('#lava_menu li').mouseout(function(){
    var pos = $("li.current").position();
 $("#google").animate({
    left: pos.left,
    right: pos.right,
    top: pos.top,
    bottom: pos.bottom
    },"fast");  
    break;      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Komlan/NgEkr/

Comment: Hey could not understand what do you mean by Lag here ? Please explain in some detail what exactly you want.

Comment: i meant that it always go back and forth before staying over the element

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `stop` method of jquery http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Change your javascript code like

```
//MOVE MOUSE ICON --Mouse out
$('#lava_menu li').mouseout(function(){
    var pos = $("li.current").position();
         $("#google").animate({
            left: pos.left,
            right: pos.right,
            top: pos.top,
            bottom: pos.bottom
            },"fast").stop(true, true);  //using stop
});
```

You need some additional code to create it more effective

Demo for this http://jsfiddle.net/NgEkr/1/

Comment: It is killing animation some what.

Comment: Yes it doesnt go back to the current link when the mouve is out

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NgEkr/2/)** its solved now that image moves back and forth as required.

Your code for `mouseover` and `mouseout` was called twice don't know why. Here I have used toggle function for mouse Hover(over and out). Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/events-hover.htm) to learn about hover (over and out).